# How to catch and hold an ImageButton status to change to a third image?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Currently there is the following function - press `Ston` and the image changes to a `Ston`.

code for start and stop function:

```
button.Touch += (object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e) =>
        {
            if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.ButtonPress)
            {

            }

        };
```

The ok sign may not appear as an additional `else if` in the code above.

How to hold the stop sign and then click it again for the ok sign?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the `button.Touch` event to another function like this:

```
button.Touch += (object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e) => {
    if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.ButtonPress)
    {
        button.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_start);
    }
    else if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
    {
        button.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_stop);
        button.Touch += (object stopButtonSender, View.TouchEventArgs stopButtonEventArgs) => {

            // Your logic for showing OK sign
        };
    }
};
```

Make sure you unsubscribed the previous event in order to prevent memory leaks.

```
button.Touch -= your_function;
```

Comment: I made an change to the code. sender and e were declared in the same scope at the second `Touch += ` declaration. Basically changing sender to sender2 and e to e2 would solve this problem.

Comment: Make sure that you're checking for `MotionEventActions.ButtonPress` in your logic for showing the OK sign.

Answer (score 0):

> How to catch and hold an ImageButton status to change to a third image?

You could use a variable :

```
int i = 1;
```

Change its value every time when your `ImageButton` was clicked :

```
bt_im.Click += (sender, e) => 
{
    if (i % 3 == 0)
    {
        bt_im.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_stop);
        i++;
        //Next time your ImageButton was clicked will set a ic_start image.
    }
    else if(i % 3 == 1)
    {
        bt_im.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_OK);
        i++;
    }
    else if (i % 3 == 2)
    {
        bt_im.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_start);
        i++;
    }

};
```

Comment: @W4y, what's you mean "a sperate click on the StopButton" ?

Comment: @W4y, what is the effect you want? Please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: @W4y, I have update my answer, is this the effect you want ?

Comment: No sorry, the requirement above is another. What I have described differs from the behavior of the second `else if` in your solution.